# Database connection Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, mysql, database, xamarin

I am new in XAMARIN ANDROID development.

I want build an App with Database Selection.
I add the NuGet package "MySQL.DATA".

Now I build a connection to the database and want to select some records.
This is my code:

```
public static List<DateTime> LoadInitialDatePicker()
    {
        List<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime>();
        var conn = GetConnection();
        new I18N.West.CP1250();

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT day FROM DienstDay", conn);
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    dateList.Add(reader.GetDateTime("day"));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            //throw;
        }

        return dateList;
    }

    private static MySqlConnection GetConnection()
    {

        string connString = "User Id=xxx;pwd=XXXX;Server=sql11.xxx.xxx;Port=3306;database=xxx";

        return new MySqlConnection(connString);
    }
```

I tried to use "I18N.West.CP1250()", but that doesn't help.

My exception is a follows:

> {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception. --->

What can I do? :(

Comment: have you tried catching the exception?

Comment: Try go deeper to the exception. Click on inner exception when the exception will show and there will be the message. Maybe from this message you will have exactly error

Comment: Is that a valid connection string?